# How do I refactor my RecyclerView code to work with a ViewModel and LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a `Fragment` in my Android app that has a `RecyclerView` and I want to save the `RecyclerView` data it previously had before the app closed and restore the data it saved onto the `RecyclerView` when the app opens again?

This is my `RecyclerView.Adapter` class:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val recyclerList: List<RecyclerCard>, private val listener: OnRecyclerClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>() {
    inner class RecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        val recyclerImageView: AppCompatImageView =
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_picture_image_view)
        val recyclerTitleView: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_title_text_view)
        val recyclerScoreView: AppCompatTextView =
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_score_text_view)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onRecyclerClick(position)
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnRecyclerClickListener {
        fun onRecyclerClick(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_card, parent, false)
        return RecyclerViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentRecycler = recyclerList[position]
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(currentRecycler.recyclerImage)
            .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
            .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .into(holder.recyclerImageView)
        holder.recyclerTitleView.text = currentRecycler.recyclerTitle
        holder.recyclerScoreView.text = currentRecycler.recyclerScore
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = recyclerList.size
}
```

And this is my `Fragment` that populates the `RecyclerView`. Note that I removed a lot of the code as it wasn't relevant to my question, but this is the main code to work with:

```
class Main : Fragment(), RecyclerAdapter.OnRecyclerClickListener {
    private lateinit var mainRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var mainList = ArrayList<RecyclerCard>()
    private var adapter = RecyclerAdapter(mainList, this)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        mainRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val item = RecyclerCard(
                string1,
                string2,
                score,
                string3
            )
            mainList += item
            this@Main.requireActivity()
                .runOnUiThread(kotlinx.coroutines.Runnable {
                    run {
                        mainRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        mainRecyclerView.layoutManager =
                            LinearLayoutManager(this@Main.requireContext())
                        mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
                    }
                })
        }
    }


    override fun onRecyclerClick(position: Int) {
        // Complete an action when the user clicks on a row item
    }
}
```

So everything works as I want to with the `RecyclerView`, what I want to do now is use a `ViewModel` and `LiveData` to save the data in the `RecyclerView` before the app is closed and then restore the data back into the `RecyclerView` when the app opens again. How do I do that? I'm having trouble refactoring my existing code to make this work. I want to do this with a `ViewModel` and `LiveData` as I believe this is the best practice for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> You usually request a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity object's onCreate() method. The system may call onCreate() several times throughout the life of an activity, such as when a device screen is rotated. The ViewModel exists from when you first request a ViewModel until the activity is finished and destroyed.

An instance of viewmodel also gets `onCleared()` when `onDestory()` is called , so you if you want to save data and position of recyclerView you need to store data in database and position of adapter (if needed) in preferences or database so you can extract when needed.

Answer (score 0):

While `ViewModel` and `LiveData` are great tools, they do not solve your problem of storing data more permanently. Instead, you need to learn how to save your data to a file or database. I suggest you look at the Room API for this.